# cannot connect to mongoDB on digital ocean cloud through goDaddy Cpanel

Tags: node.js, mongodb, networking, cpanel, digital-ocean

I have a subdomain on goDaddy cpanel. I want to run my nodejs project on that. Everything is working fine except i can't connect to my mongoDB which is on digital ocean server. it connects perfectly locally but can't connect on Cpanel. I'm using mongoose for connection.

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MongoDB_URI_STRING, 
                {
                    useNewUrlParser: true,
                    useUnifiedTopology: true,
                })
                . then(() => {
                    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server PORT: ${PORT}`))
```

when i run the project through Cpanel Terminal it gives this Error:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 188.166.164.225:27017 did not connect to server
```

It's working fine locally. Any Suggestion would be much appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

I thought maybe the problem is with .env from where i'm passing cluster string for connection, i passed it on connect but got the same result.

Comment: What is the connection string?